# In java, how do I count the lines of a file which contain the same value?

Tags: java, file, readfile

I have is a file containing the below content.

```
c,10  
r,20.3,12.1  
t,32.1,12.2  
c,34  
r,1.3,4.9
```

I only want the count of the lines containing 'c' as the first token.

Answer (score 3):

I'd stream the file lines and evaluate them with `startsWith`:

```
long numLines =
    Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file")).filter(s -> s.startsWith("c")).count();
```